# Why website does not change even if I turn off cache

Tags: html, caching, web

I have added these lines to my header (thinking it will delete server cache):

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I cleared my browser cache and turned it off.
Now when I modify a page it doesn't change. I even deleted that page and it still shows the same content. How could it be?
I am 100% positive that I am inspecting the right page...
Thanks!

Comment: Dont use HTML-Meta cache options, the most browsers will ignore it. Set the Caching header in your HTTP-Response.

Comment: maybe it's server side cached

Comment: Ok, done that and it changed, finally. Thanks! I'm starting to really hate cache..